# How to normalize with PCA and scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let me keep this brief. Basically what I want to know is: should I do this,

```
pca.fit(normalize(x))
new=pca.transform(normalize(x))
```

or this

```
pca.fit(normalize(x))
new=pca.transform(x)
```

I know that we should normalize our data before using PCA but which one of the procedures above is correct with sklearn?

Comment: What type of normalization do you mean exactly? I added an answer where I standardize the data before PCA, but you can choose other types of normalization even with that same object.

Comment: To fit to and then transform the same data, use `fit_transform`. It's more efficient, esp. for PCA which computes the transformation as part of its training step.

Comment: I have asked a followup question for when you want to normalize for PCA on all data, but apply this PCA on data separately. So the question is about how to normalize the separately data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646915/normalize-pca-with-scikit-learn-when-data-is-split

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In general, you would want to use the first option.

Your normalization places your data in a new space which is seen by the PCA and its transform basically expects the data to be in the same space.

Scikit-learn provides tools to do this transparently and conveniently by concatenating estimators in a pipeline. Try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(20, 40)

pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA(n_components=5))])

pipeline.fit_transform(data)
```

The prepended scaler will then always apply its transformation to the data before it goes to the PCA object.

As @larsmans points out, you may want to use `sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer` instead of the `StandardScaler` or, similarly, remove the mean centering from the `StandardScaler` by passing the keyword argument `with_mean=False`.

Comment: Or `make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA(n_components=5))` in 0.15.

Comment: Yes, that is a great addition in 0.15 which reduces the amount of different brackets by around half.

Comment: Note that the OP is using `normalize`, so your code should use `Normalizer` to match it with a pipeline. (They're different ways of normalizing for different types of data.)

Comment: Why does it make sense to use a scaler than divides by std? Shouldn't it be just MinMaxScaler?