# Normalize PCA with scikit-learn when data is split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a followup question on: [How to normalize with PCA and scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475465/how-to-normalize-with-pca-and-scikit-learn).

I'm creating an emotion detection system and what I do now is:

1. Split data over all emotion (distributing data over multiple subsets).
2. Add all data together (the multiple subsets into 1 set)
3. Get PCA parameters of combined data (self.pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=self.n_components, whiten=True).fit(self.data))
4. Per emotion (per subset), apply PCA to data of that emotion (subset).

I should do the normalization at: step 2) Normalize all combined data, and step 4) normalize the subsets.

### Edit

I was wondering if the normalization over all data and the normalization over subset is the same. Now when I tried to simplify my example on suggestion of @BartoszKP I figured out that how I understood the normalization worked, was wrong. The normalization in both cases work in the same way, so this is a valid way to do it, right? (see code)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.decomposition import RandomizedPCA
import numpy as np

data_1 = np.array(([52, 254], [4, 128]), dtype='f')
data_2 = np.array(([39, 213], [123, 7]), dtype='f')
data_combined = np.vstack((data_1, data_2))
#print(data_combined)
"""
Output
[[  52.  254.]
 [   4.  128.]
 [  39.  213.]
 [ 123.    7.]]
"""
#Normalize all data
data_norm = normalize(data_combined)
print(data_norm)
"""
[[ 0.20056452  0.97968054]
 [ 0.03123475  0.99951208]
 [ 0.18010448  0.98364753]
 [ 0.99838448  0.05681863]]
"""

pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=20, whiten=True)
pca.fit(data_norm)

#Normalize subset of data
data_1_norm = normalize(data_1)
print(data_1_norm)
"""
[[ 0.20056452  0.97968054]
 [ 0.03123475  0.99951208]]
"""
pca.transform(data_1_norm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as explained in [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#normalization), what `normalize` does, is scaling individual samples, independently to others:

> **Normalization** is the process of **scaling individual samples** to have unit norm.

This is additionally explained in [the documentation of the `Normalizer` class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer):

> Each sample (i.e. each row of the data matrix) with at least one non zero component **is rescaled independently of other samples** so that its norm (l1 or l2) equals one.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>