# Python scikit-learn PCA to Augment Missing Data in Historical VaR Calculation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, missing-data

I have an array of time series data I want to use to calculate historical VaR for a large equity portfolio.

The portfolio has a significant number of instruments with missing time series data and I require a systematic method of generating reasonable missing values.

I am considering PCA to augment the missing data in instances where there is sufficient data to calculate the factor exposures and have attempted the following Python implementation ([Carol Alexander](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Market-Models-Financial-Analysis-Investments/dp/0471899755)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# get index time series returns
df = pd.read_csv('IndexData.csv',index_col=0)
df = df.fillna(method='ffill').pct_change().dropna(how='all') 
rics = df.columns.tolist()

# add 'missing' data
df['GDAXI'].iloc[0:30] = None

# see stack overflow reference below
pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA(n_components = len(rics) - 1))

# Step 1 - PCA for sub-period with GDAXI data - training period
dfSub = df.iloc[30:]
pipeline.fit(np.array(dfSub))
sub_components = pipeline._final_estimator.components_

# Step 2 - PCA for entire period with no GDAXI - 
dfFull = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'GDAXI']
full_transf = pipeline.fit_transform(np.array(dfFull))

# Step 3 - Apply missing asset factor exposures in stage 1 to stage 2
#          to augment missing data
synthetic =  np.dot(full_transf, sub_components[:,rics.index('GDAXI')])

# rescaling??
df['GDAXI'].iloc[0:30]  = synthetic[0:30]
```

The example attached assumes IndexData.csv contains the price data for serveral European indices including the DAX.  In practive I would hope to operate on reasonably highly correlated country/sector baskets.

### Questions

1. What sigma and mean would / should I use to rescale the computed returns?
2. Is there already functionality to do this in an alternative Python library?

[attempt 2]

### References

[Sebastian Raschka - Implementing PCA in Python Step-By-Step](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html)

[stackOverflow - How to normalize with pca and scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475465/how-to-normalize-with-pca-and-scikit-learn)

[scikitlearn.org](http:////scikitlearn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)